# Submitting an article to another journal

Tags: soft-question

Not long ago I submitted an article to PRE. One referee was in favor and two against (this not more than 3 months ago). Rather than pressing, I decided to submit it elsewhere. A single referee report was negative on the grounds that the article was unclear, though the details helped me revise the article. Is it all right to resubmit a substantially revised article and new supporting material to PRE under the original article ID number, or am I obligated to make a new submission? In the event of the former, should (must?) I mention the intervening submission?

Comment: Not sure this has anything to do with physics, even softly...

Comment: @Moshe where else would a person go to ask such a question?

Comment: @ space_cadet and Moshe---maybe to the chat boards, if they are being used.

Comment: @space Just my opinion, not a major issue, we are not flooded with questions about practical aspects of academic life.

Comment: Sorry, but we can't afford clutter like this. Go ask on chat or ask APS.

Comment: hi, I find very interesting this discussion. I wonder why this question was closed or where is other stack exchange site (or similar) for this kind of discussions

Answer (score 5):

It seems like your questions are answered here: http://pre.aps.org/info/polproce.html, in particular:

"Authors should state whether the paper they submit has been previously considered for publication in any of the APS journals (Physical Review Letters, other Physical Review journals, or Reviews of Modern Physics) and supply the code number assigned by that journal."

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I'd send an email to the editor who reviewed the first tine you sent it. Ask him if the changes make it worth resubmitting. The fact that they agreed to review it the first time, and that it got a 3rd reviewer, are good points in its favor.